# Bootstrap dropdown checkbox select

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to customize a bootstrap dropdown with checkboxes and if I select a checkbox from dropdown the label name I want to be written on input dropdown delimited with '`;`' like in uploaded picture when `dropdown` is closed.

Here is a [**fiddle example**](http://jsfiddle.net/D2RLR/5649/).

[image]

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Not the most elegant solution - you will probably want to refine this somewhat, but this might get you started:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("ul.dropdown-menu input[type=checkbox]").each(function() {
        $(this).change(function() {
            var line = "";
            $("ul.dropdown-menu input[type=checkbox]").each(function() {
                if($(this).is(":checked")) {
                    line += $("+ span", this).text() + ";";
                }
            });
            $("input.form-control").val(line);
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 11):

I know it's a old question but still, you can use this library to do *almost* (except the exact design you asked) what you want http://davidstutz.github.io/bootstrap-multiselect/#getting-started

Answer (score 2):

The following code works in **Bootstrap 4.1** if you add a function to show the menu on hover, but when you click the < li > then your checkboxes becomes unclickable. Anybody having a better solution please provide.

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-form">
  <li><label class="checkbox"><input type="checkbox">One</label></li>
  <li><label class="checkbox"><input type="checkbox">Two</label></li>
</ul>
```

And add these JS codes:

```
// Allow Bootstrap dropdown menus to have forms/checkboxes inside, 
// and when clicking on a dropdown item, the menu doesn't disappear.
$(document).on('click', '.dropdown-menu.dropdown-menu-form', function(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
});
```

**UPDATE**

The below code is working good but checkboxes events are fired twice so had to choose the `onchange` event instead of `onclick`

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-form">
  <li><label class="checkbox"><input type="checkbox" onchange="some()">One</label></li>
  <li><label class="checkbox"><input type="checkbox" onchange="some()">Two</label></li>
</ul>
```

and the jquery code as follows:

```
$(document).on('click', '.dropdown-menu', function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```