# dropdown checkbox list cakephp

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.5

Can we do something like image below on cakephp. If can, how to do it? I am struggle with it. I try to find any answers but can not found something like this. Any answers for this problem will be great appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can also be done with Bootstrap as well. The functionality is generally the same as @Anubhav 's answer from a bit earlier, however this is a little cleaner and a more up to date solution. The Bootstrap Framework is maintained/updated a lot more frequently.

[image]

See here for full solution:

[Bootstrap dropdown checkbox select](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23103567/bootstrap-dropdown-checkbox-select)

Answer (score 0):

No you cant do this using only CakePHP... but the above thing can be done using jQuery.

Please follow the link and your task will be done easily

http://dropdown-check-list.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/doc/dropdownchecklist.html

Cheers

Comment: The link is dead.

Answer (score 0):

```
multiple dropdown options with checkbox in cakephp error

<div class="col-md-2 place-grid">
                <h5>Property Type</h5>
                    <?php $allCategories=$this->Common->getCategories(); ?>
                    <?php echo $this->Form->input('ptype',array('options' =>$allCategories,'style'=>'width:150px;','error'=>false,'id'=>'ptype','onchange'=>'getIdType()','div'=>false,'label'=>false,'empty'=>'Select Type','class'=>"sel"));   ?>
                    <?php if($this->Form->error('ptype')){?>
                    <?php echo $this->Form->error('ptype',array('style'=>'txtError'));?>
                    <?php } ?>
                </div>



                <div class="col-md-2 place-grid">
                <h5>Sub Type</h5>


                    <?php $allSubCategories=$this->Common->getArticleSubCategories(); ?>

                    <?php echo $this->Form->input('sptype',array('options'=>'', 'style'=>'width:150px;','error'=>false,'div'=>false,'select'=>true,'label'=>false,'empty'=>'fgfg','class'=>"sel"));   ?>                          

                </div>
```