# JQuery: How to Choose values from multiselect

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-multiselect

I want to make a month list drop down menu which will choose values instead of option text.I used JQuery Multiselect.js and this is the code:
***Notice: CDN Links Don't work here.But i've lib file that works fine.***

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Multi-select Dropdown List with Checkbox by CodexWorld</title>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.multiselect/1.13/jquery.multiselect.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<style>
body { font-family:'Open Sans' Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif}
ul,li { margin:0; padding:0; list-style:none;}
.label { color:#000; font-size:16px;}
</style>
</head>
<body>
    
<h2>jQuery MultiSelect Basic Uses</h2>
<select name="langOpt[]" multiple id="langOpt" >
 <option value="All">All</option>
 <option value="Jan">January</option>
 <option value="Feb">February</option>
 <option value="Mar">March</option>
 <option value="Apr">April</option>
 <option value="May">May</option>
 <option value="Jun">June</option>
 <option value="Jul">July</option>
 <option value="Aug">August</option>
 <option value="Sep">September</option>
 <option value="Oct">October</option>
 <option value="Nov">November</option>
 <option value="Dec">December</option>
</select>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.multiselect/1.13/jquery.multiselect.js"></script>
<script>
$('#langOpt').multiselect({ 
    placeholder: 'Select Months'
});

</script>



</body>
</html>
```

The given code is working fine for option text.However if an user choose: November and December then i want to output option values: **Nov, Dec**.

Please Help Thanks.

Comment: try `$(document).on("change","#langOpt",function(){console.log($(this).val());})`, this will give an array with selected options

Comment: Thanks @Jacky Shek.Its almost done.But,I want the values to display on the selectbox instead of console log.please help.thanks

Comment: You have another selectbox or you want to display the value in the same selectbox?

Comment: Thanks @Jacky Shek.I want in the same box.thanks

Answer (score 1):

It's better to have drop-down checkbox instead of multiple select.

You check the question below

[Bootstrap dropdown checkbox select](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23103567/bootstrap-dropdown-checkbox-select)

Also try that one and let me know

http://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/jQuery-Multiple-Select-Plugin-For-Bootstrap-Bootstrap-Multiselect/

Cheer